# MOSS WCM - Best way to customise a list item view

Tags: sharepoint, moss, list

I am createing an external facing SharePoint site which contains a number of custom lists. Some of these are extremely complicated.

I generally avoid using the SharePoint Designer like the plague, preferring to stick to Visual Studio.

To display a list item to users should I really try and get my head around making a custom DispForm.aspx or would is it better to create my own custom asp.net page, pass the item id into it and populate the page using code behind?

If I go the second option is there a way to 'bind' the list item to the page so I can directly access the fields or would I have to do literal replacement etc?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a completely seperate ASP.Net page that just referenced the List and displayed items as needed with query parameters etc

This worked well

Answer (score 0):

Best thing to do is, customize the form in SP Designer and use a feature to deploy the modified list pages.

You can do this by modifying the list schema.xml and specifiying your custom list pages at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Its depends on what Kind of customization you wanted in the Display form.

1. Are you trying to get the Custom Look and Feel for the Display Form ? (Try setting the **System Master page** to your Branded Master page)
2. Are you trying to get the Fields arranged in a different fashion unlike Two column listing? ( You need to create a Custom **ListItemIterator & Rendering Template)**  Refer [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa543922.aspx) for more information. Once you have the ListIterator then you need to write a custom List Template and in the end of Schema.xml you need to set the Template to your custom Template.

   ```
   <Forms>
       <Form Type="DisplayForm" Url="DispForm.aspx" Template="CustomListForm" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
   ```
3. And to answer the second Question on how to bind. You can Try out [SPDataSource](http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2008/06/spdatasource-every-sharepoint-developer.html) and [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/sharepointdesigner/archive/2007/04/24/spdatasource-and-rollups-with-the-data-view.aspx).This will allow you get the details for the Single Item.Specify the mode to **ListItem**